# How to retrieve document number (AR SO etc)

Tags: customization, payment, acumatica

I am creating a payment plugin for Acumatica. I have it processing fine but would like to send the Invoice number or Sales order number to the gateway so when looking at reports in the gateway they can look up transaction by invoice or SO #.
How can I retrieve the that info when in the payments context? All I am getting in that context currently is doctype PMT and that payment number.

```
public class CardConnectProcessing : ICCPaymentProcessing
{
    public override bool DoTransaction(PX.CCProcessingBase.CCTranType aType, PX.CCProcessingBase.ProcessingInput aInputData, PX.CCProcessingBase.ProcessingResult aResult)
        {
            var Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Params.Add("orderid", aInputData.DocType + aInputData.DocRefNbr );

    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to help without some code.

Comment: Providing at lease a brief code example will help with an answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think the code block would be helpful.
The Params object is data sent to the Payment Gateway. I need to include the Invoice or Sales Order number.